# Arithmetic using sysconf() return values produces incorrect value in C

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to get a little brute force program up and running and will be storing the plain text in a buffer and using multiple other threads to manipulate it. Since I am filling a buffer I would like to monitor how much free ram I have left and pause while I there is about 10% free RAM left.

Everything seems to work fine with the exception of the final division.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "common.h"

void* Brute_force(void *arg)
{
    int length = *(int*) arg;
    long int percent = 10;
    long int available_pages = sysconf(_SC_AVPHYS_PAGES);
    long int pages = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
    long int total_pages = sysconf(_SC_PHYS_PAGES);
    long int free_mem = available_pages/total_pages;
    printf("Available_pages: %ld\n",available_pages);
    printf("PageSize: %ld\n",pages);
    printf("Physical_pages: %ld\n",total_pages);
    printf("%ld free memory left\n",free_mem);
    long int multiple = pages * total_pages;
    printf("%ld\n",multiple);
    long int final = available_pages/multiple;
    printf("%ld\n",final);
}
```

I am having issues with free_mem (along with final as they are identical). Everything else prints out correctly, though as soon as I do available_pages/multiple and print it out, it gives me a zero and I have no idea when since when I do multiple/available_pages it gives me a non-zero number. I am assuming that sysconf() returns a long, as per the man page and so I have no idea why this last step fails. Any insight?

Comment: How do you expect an int (long or not) to represent a value between 0 and 1?

Comment: hmmm, fair enough, though I don't really care about the accuracy to such an extent. My understanding is that the int will round and that will be good enough. The problem is, is that it is seemingly not doing that. Am I missing something else very obvious?

Comment: Again, you're using integers. You're dividing free pages by total pages. Free pages is, presumably, less than or equal to total, right? So what result do you expect, as an integer?

Comment: Oh jesus! Clearly I have been at this too long, because that is painfully obvious... Thank you.

Comment: this line: 'long int free_mem = available_pages/total_pages;'  will not work because total_pages is greater than available_pages and this is an integer divide.   suggest: ''long int free_mem = (available_pages*pages)/total_pages;  suggest 'pages' be renamed to 'page_size'

Comment: this line: 'long int final = available_pages/multiple;' will not work because multiple is much larger than available_pages and this is an integer divide